# Error when retrieving saved object using pickle

Tags: python, object, pickle, agent-based-modeling

Working with the MESA agent based modelling package. Using pickle to save the state of my intermediate model. But when retrieving the saved model the execution ends up in error saying:

````
  File "/home/demonwolf/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/main.py", line 281, in <module>
    empty_model = pickle.load(f)
  File "/home/demonwolf/anaconda3/envs/ABM/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte```



Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: What is your variable ```f```? generally the format for pickle.load is ```pickle.load(open("PATH", "rb"))``` ("rb" is if it was dumped using "wb" , binary mode not string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file (the `f` parameter in `pickle.load(f)`) should be open in binary read (`rb`) mode， not the default text (`r`) mode.

```
with open("path/to/your/pickle.bin", "rb") as f:
    empty_model = pickle.load(f)
```